Testing routes with load balancer in Spring Cloud Gateway
Is there a way to test the route in Spring Cloud Gateway with the format of lb://service-name. Since there is no instance of Eureka running in SpringBootTest, I defined the bean of ServiceInstanceListSupplier which returns the single mock server instance but the route to mock server always returns 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE. Is there an example of the test which sets the route with lb scheme and resolves the url to a mock service?
Here's the configuration I tried
@TestConfiguration
    static class ServiceInstanceSupplier {

        @Bean
        ServiceInstanceListSupplier serviceInstanceListSupplier() {
            return new ServiceInstanceListSupplier() {
                @Override
                public String getServiceId() {
                    return "mock-service";
                }

                @Override
                public Flux<List<ServiceInstance>> get() {
                    return Flux.just(
                            List.of(new DefaultServiceInstance("mock-service-1", "mock-service", "localhost", wireMockServer.port(), false))
                    );
                }
            };
        }
    }

